# github initialization problems

Tags: git, github

After reading many tutorials on both rails and git --- I still can not
find anyone that lays out a working set of commands to do the following:

I have a local group of files and have local git repository set up.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Repository"
```

I have an account at GITHUB and I have a proper SSH Key

But here is were everything falls apart - I can NOT PUSH to github.

Comment: you are missing the `git remote add` step to connect to the github repo

Comment: Would be helpful if you paste the output here when you try to push.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your local repository to the remote one on Github then push

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Comment: Thanks to responders.  Apparently none of the tutorials ever mention

Comment: initially having to manually setup the repository on github.  I did that and everything is now working.  Thanks I hope this information helps others! -